# Can PHP interact with a website?

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible for PHP to log into websites and interact with them?

If so, what technologies do I need to start looking into?

Basically, what I need to do is fill out forms using PHP. I suppose cURL could do this, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, it can. You'll need HTTP. Beyond that, good luck.

Comment: Too broad and needs more info. Is it always going to be the same forms? If so, you won't need to do any html parsing, just send the requests. To log in you would have to use curl to send login request, grab the returned session id cookie and add this to following requests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but basically:

1. Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the HTML of a page.
2. Parse the HTML and find form elements (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/840973) on HTML parsing).
3. Generate data to submit based on the inputs in the form.
4. Use cURL to create a request to the submit attribute of the form (making sure to use the specified method).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured I'd need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need curl: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Yeah, he knows that, he said so in his question

Comment: Well his question was too broad in the first place, wasn't it?

Comment: @Cyclone Yes he did say he knows of it. But it doesn't mean that Vladimir's answer is wrong.